# c# Sql between statement

Tags: sql, between

I'm trying to sort customers billings and i need to sort them by different time periods.

What I've been trying is:

```
(select billing_date from [transaktions] 
 between '" + start + "' and '" +stop+"' where konto_nr = @konto_nr")
```

also

```
(select billing_date from [transaktions] where konto_nr = @konto_nr" between '" + start + "' and '" +stop+"')
```

start = the starting period of the date
stop = the ending of the period

The error message I'm getting is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'between'.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't/won't use stored procedures for these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax should be something like

```
where Transaktions.Billing_Date between StartDate and EndDate
```

of the obvious respective columns and variable names you are working with.  Yes, you referred to the "billing_date" as a selected column, but the WHERE can be testing OTHER columns of criteria so you have to explicitly identify it there too.

Answer (score 2):

First of all : you should **never** concatenate together your SQL statement! That's a big big open door for SQL injection attacks....

Second: you need to put your `BETWEEN` clause into a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT billing_date 
FROM dbo.[transaktions] 
WHERE Billing_Date BETWEEN @Start AND @EndDate
AND konto_nr = @konto_nr
```